# Change file icon OS X

Tags: macos, icon, preferences, file

I tried following [Apple's instruction](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH19073?viewlocale=en_US) to change a file icon, but it didn't work they way I expected.

### Details

**File type**:  "web internet location" or `Inbox.webloc`

So this it what I've tried so far.

[image]

^ Right click `Get Info`

[image]

Copied the icon file

[image]

And... pasted

[image]

**Result**

[image]

Not what I expected... Am I missing something? How do I change this file **icon** without using apple script?

Answer (score 4):

Follow these steps:

1. Get **into** on your icon file (open it for example with `Preview`).
2. Select the icon with <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>.
3. Copy the selected icon with <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>.
4. Paste it over onto the webloc file (as you're doing) with <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>.

Basically, **don't paste the file onto the icon, copy the icon of the icon**.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Fasticns](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/22759/fasticns) - drop your artwork onto it. Copy as Image from the Edit menu then paste it into your file's Get Info spot as you have tried already. (FastIcns is free)

Answer (score 0):

You need a proper .icns file to do this.

iConvert Icons has the best converter around:
http://iconverticons.com/online/

Comment: That link is dead now. It seems to be this: https://www.careerigniter.com/convert-png-ico-and-icns-icons/ (non-free app)